# Find every possible user to user travel time duration using pgr_dijkstra or pgr_kDijkstra

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, osm2pgrouting, osmconvert

I have this below GetNearest function that will get every user's nearest node from ways (imported using osm2pgrouting).

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION GetNearest(NUMERIC, NUMERIC) 
  RETURNS BIGINT AS 
  $$
  SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr AS vertices 
  ORDER BY vertices.the_geom <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint($1, $2), 4326) LIMIT 1;
  $$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Below is the query that runs and insert into another table the every possible user to user travel time duration.

```
INSERT INTO "UserTravelTime" ("FromLat", "FromLng", "ToLat", "ToLng", "Duration", "CreatedOn", "UpdatedOn")
SELECT C1."Lat" AS "FromLat", C1."Lng" AS "FromLng", C2."Lat" AS "ToLat", C2."Lng" "ToLng", 
  (SELECT ROUND(SUM(cost)) AS Cost FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT gid AS id,
         source,
         target,
         cost_s as cost
        FROM ways',
    (SELECT GetNearest(C1."Lng", C1."Lat")), (SELECT GetNearest(C2."Lng", C2."Lat")),
    directed := true)),
    NOW(),
    NOW()
  FROM 
  "UserCoordinate" C1,
  "UserCoordinate" C2;
```

It works but it takes a lot of time to complete nearly 15 minutes, is there anything that I am doing wrong or could do better to make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I needed only the cost and not the entire path, I used [pgr_dijkstraCost](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstraCost.html) to calculate the costs and now it takes only 2 minutes for more than a million records.

I have also added another column to user information to store the nearest osm node and that made my query much faster than expected.

Below is the query.

```
INSERT INTO "UserTravelTime" ("FromId", "ToId", "Duration", "ParentId", "CreatedOn", "UpdatedOn")
SELECT *, NULL, NOW(), NOW() FROM pgr_dijkstraCost(
    'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, cost_s as cost, reverse_cost_s as reverse_cost FROM ways',
    ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT "OsmNodeId" FROM "UserCoordinate"), 
    ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT "OsmNodeId" FROM "UserCoordinate"), 
    directed := true) AS "Duration";
```